# Is there special solution to have fragments inside of ViewPager2?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, fragment, androidx

I have some pages in my app, each page is a fgrament with it's own ViewModel, and all of them are swapping each other in FrameLayout(I have special BottomNavigationView to handle their swaps).

So I want to replace FrameLayout with ViewPager2, but in such case I have to provide Views not Fragments to RecyclerView.Adapter and my solution is to wrap fragments into some views, for example LinearLayout.

So my question is: am I right that it's the easiest solution to make it? and is there any better solution?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your point. can you explain this? "I have to provide Views not Fragments to RecyclerView.Adapter and my solution is to wrap fragments into some views"

Comment: I mean that ViewPager2 is working through Recyclerview.Adapter and ViewHolders inside of them must be created with View(restriction by primary View Holder constructor) , which will be the root of page

Answer (score 5):

ViewPager2 can use multiple types of adapters not just the RecyclerView.Adapter

If you want to use Fragments with state, just simply make a custom adapter that extends FragmentStateAdapter and implement the necessary methods. Your custom adapter should look something like this:

```
class MyCustomPagerAdapter(
    activity: FragmentActivity,
    private val fragments: List<Fragment>) : FragmentStateAdapter(activity) {

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return fragments.size
    }

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return fragments[position]
    }
}
```

Then simply set viewPager.adapter to your custom adapter. Each fragment will have its own state, and the FragmentStateAdapter implements StatefulAdapter, so your fragments are automatically a part of the lifecycle.

There's an example here: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-viewpager2

However, if your views don't need state of their own, it's best to just use views with the RecyclerView.Adapter. You'll get much better performance.